# Chrome Selenium Dont work output audio "use-file-for-fake-audio-capture"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

No voice sending

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--allow-file-access-from-files')
options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
options.add_argument('--mute-audio')

options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=1.wav")
```

I'm checking here https://driversol.com/ru/tests/webcamtest/check
the audio interface is replaced with fake, but the audio is not sent